# How to find the Verticle Average of a Martrix?

Tags: arrays, math, matrix, average

Given a 2 dimensional array ie.

```
array m = [[1,2],
           [2,4],
           [6,6]]
```

How would one take the verticle average of said array, producing something like:

```
//[(1+2+6)/ 3, (2+4+6)/3]
Console: [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pseudo Code:**

```
ans = []
for i in range(len(arr[0])):
    temp = 0
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        temp += arr[j][i]
    ans.append(temp/len(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    avg[i]=0;
    for(j=0;j<m[i].length;j++){
        avg[i]+=m[i];
    }
    avg[i]/=m[i].length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a m x n matrix M, form the 1 x m matrix

```
w = (1.0/m .. 1.0/m)
```

and compute the 1 x n matrix

```
v = w*M.
```

The enties in v are your 'vertical averages'